# How to print block generated by views in the tpl file?

Tags: 6, blocks

I have a block with name: "Share Product"(block number 5) generated by my view with name: "main_product_deal". In this view i have 9 blocks.

Now in my .tpl file i need to print this block.

I have seen the function 'module_invoke' but not working.
My code is:

```
//On my tpl file
<?php    
$block = module_invoke('views','block','view',"main_product_deal-block_5");
print $block['content'];
?>
```

I working in drupal 6.x. Is it correct my code? Or exist another solution?
Note: I can not set the block in the administration, because I'm programming certain things in the tpl

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried views_embed_view()?
http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/6

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the block, or can you just output the results of the view?  If you just need the results of the view:

```
$view = views_get_view('main_product_deal');
print $view->execute_display('default');
```

Comment: The param of execute_display is the name of the view or the delta?.. I'll try your solution.

Comment: Don't work :(. A put this in my tpl file.. but doesn't show the result of the view-block.

Comment: What does it do? Are there any error messages?  More info would be great

Comment: Any errors, only don't show the block.
I need to show a block-views in my page-deals.tpl... I need extract only this block. (no the default)